# c# Object obj's value is {}. What is "{}"?

Tags: c#, sql, object, null

I'm using some old code that runs a sql query as a reference.

At some point, it gets to something like:

```
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
DataRow dataRow = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
Object obj = dataRow[fieldName];
```

The old code does:

```
string output;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString())) { output = obj.ToString(); }
else { output = "Not Available"; }
```

I changed them to:

```
output = obj as string ?? "Not Available"
```

But sometimes, it broke. As I suspected, it was happening breaking when the entry was an `int`. Casting as an `int` in those cases solved that problem.

Then another problem arose when there was *no* entry for `obj[fieldName]` of type int. When I stepped through the debugger, I was surprised to find that `obj` wasn't `null`. In VS, mousing over revealed it had a value `{}`.

What the heck is `{}`? How do I make a boolean test of it?

(In the old code, it appears `.ToString()` returns `""` in this case and works as expected.)

Comment: It is [DBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{` and `}` are opening and closing braces and symbolic of the start and finish of an object. Hence an empty object with no special properties is depicted in shorthand as `{}`. The debugger uses this notation to help you visually distinguish between an empty object, an empty string and null.

If you hover over `obj[fieldName]` and there is no entry for `fieldName`, the debugger won't care about that, it'll show the value of `obj`. You'll have to use the *immediate* window or a watch/quickwatch. The debugger will only see you hovering over obj and assume you're referring to the array itself, not the contents of the array at the specified index.

Comment: And there isn't an `Object.Empty` for `obj == Object.Empty` test? Or will can I create a `Object comparableEmpty = new Object()`?

Comment: No, because `Object` is a reference type, which means if it existed, comparing Object.Empty to your own object would always be false. You could possibly use `myObj.GetType().GetProperties().Count == 0` or some variation thereof, though the overhead is probably not worth it.

Comment: Feels kinda dumb how there isn't an elegant solution for this. If it's a reference type, the reference should just be `null` like a good little reference.

Comment: Any empty array is not null. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of a few basic things. I'll try to update my answer with a bit more information.

Comment: Then you're saying that an `Object` is more like a container than a reference. A container that can only have one item and no convenient way to check to see if it's empty.

Comment: `Object` is the base class for ALL types in .Net. You are referring to it as though it is something special. It is in fact, *less* special than any other type. It's also not a container the way you're referring to. It's just a type with no properties and no methods other than the most most basic methods shared by all types (seeing as they are inherited from `Object` anyway).

Comment: Well, either there's a way to test if it's an empty object or not, or my only solution is to do `obj.ToString()` and see if that returns `null` or `""`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by testing for an empty object? I don't understand. There is no reason to do this, I think, in the context you are talking about. Are you talking about testing for an empty array?

Comment: I've figured out what I need to do. `obj.getType().Equals(System.DBNull.Value)`. In my question, I stated that I needed a boolean for control flow to handle when an entry is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across again this problem.

Solution if val object is shown {} in debug mode

```
// Check if its not null or empty
if (!IsNullOrEmpty(val.ToString().ToArray()))
{
    // Do something with val
    dt.Rows.Add(val);
}

public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T[] array)
{
    return array == null || array.Length == 0;
}
```