# Function returning named ValueTuple and success flag

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, c#-8.0

I am running into this situation again and again, I want a function to return both a named ValueTuple and a success flag

All the options I can think of are not great :(

**Option1:**

```
bool MyFunc(T1 param, out (Type1 name1, Type2 name2)? result)

if (!MyFunc(param, out var result)) { .. .. my error handling }

.. do stuff with `result.Value.name1` and `result.Value.name2`
```

Ugly with needing to define result and needing `result.Value` everywhere

**Option2:**

```
bool MyFunc(T1 param, out (Type1 name1, Type2 name2)? result)

if (!MyFunc(param, out var result)) { .. .. my error handling }
var (name1, name2) = result.Value;

.. do stuff with name1, name2
```

Ugly with needing to define result and to explicitly destruct the tuple

**Option 3**:

```
(Type1 name1, Type2 name2)? MyFunc(Type3 param) {}

var myFuncRes = myFunc(param);
if (myFuncRes is null) { .. my error handling }

.. do stuff with myFuncRes.Value.name1 etc
```

Ugly with needing `myFuncRes` and `.Value` or explicitly destructing the tuple

What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
(Type1 name1, Type2 name2)? MyFunc(T1 param)

if (var myFuncRes = MyFunc(param) is null) { .. .. my error handling }

.. do stuff with `myFuncRes.name1` and `myFuncRes.name2` directly !
```

This is my explicit intention .. but this is not allowed

Are there better ways or common solutions ?

(Note I am not interested in throwing exceptions here)

Comment: Is the success flag part of your Tuple?

Comment: It seems like you want to have your cake and eat it too.  You could wrap your name1/2 tuple with a separate tuple that also includes result, but that would still require destructuring.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/611

Comment: If you do include a success flag you can use pattern matching with the success constant, eg `if (MyFunc() is (true,var someValue)){ useThat(someValue);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find out a better way I feel:

```
    (bool success, (string name1, string name2)) MyFunc() {
      if (DateTime.Now.Year > 2020) return (false, ("", "")); // error 
      return (true, ("some value", "some value"));
    }

    void F() {
      if (!(MyFunc() is (true, var (name1, name2)))) return;
      Console.WriteLine(name1);
      .. do stuff with name1 and name2
    }
```

This is reasonably clear and concise and does not introduce any unneeded variables

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
(Type1 name1, Type2 name2)? MyFunc() {...} 

if (!(MyFunc() is {} myFuncRes))
{
    // Error handling
    return;
}
// use myFuncRes.name1 and myFuncRes.name2
```

This uses [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). `{}` is a property pattern which doesn't actually specify any properties, and so it matches any object which is not `null`. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982658/c-sharp-object-objs-value-is-what-is).

It's not hugely readable, though, IMO. There are discussions about adding new patterns to improve cases like this, such as `is not null`.

There's also [a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/611) to improve the case of destructuring a tuple in an out declaration, which would let you write:

```
bool MyFunc(out (Type1 name1, Type2 name2) result) {...} 

if (!MyFunc(out var (name1, name2)) 
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the expansion.  Interesting usage of pattern matching...I'll have to look at that.

That doesn't seem to exactly solve the OP's problem since all that means is that null is the result, whereas they are looking for an explicit boolean result.  That said, clever trick :).

Comment: @DavidL I think this meets the "what I would like to be able to do is..." bit at the end of their question?

Comment: @canton7 I didn't originally read the OP's question that way but I can see how you could make that argument.

Comment: "There are discussions about adding new patterns to improve cases like this, such as is not null" - where ?

Comment: @kofifus on https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues, where language discussions take place

Answer (score 1):

Why not use nested tuples?

```
static ((int name1, int name2) result, bool success) Test()
{
    return ((1, 1), true);
}

static void Main()
{
    var x = Test();
    if (x.success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your numbers are {0} and {1}", x.result.name1, x.result.name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you deal with failure ? Set the inner tuple to null ? Then you will need x.result.Value.name1 etc

Comment: I imagine they could be set to `default(int)` or `default(T)` in the general case. Anyway, if a failure corresponds to a null return value then why do you need a Boolean flag to begin with?

Comment: the main issue I have with this is having to define x and therefore have the whole thing in two lines which breaks the flow thanks

Comment: I see. I probably don't share your style priorities, but it's a fun puzzle. Please check my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

[C# tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) were designed to represent a bag of variables (like local variables in a function) and not entities.

If you're treating the tuple as a unit, you're, most probably, doing something wrong.

The original method, in the first place, should be:

```
bool MyFunc(T1 param, out Type1 name1, out Type2 name2)
```

And if you can't have out parameters (if it's an asynchronous method, for example), it should be:

```
(bool success, Type1 name1, Type2 name2) MyFunc(T1 param)
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to return those results would be :

```
(bool success, string name1, string name2) MyFunc(bool param)
{
    return param ? (true,"A","B")
                 :default;
}
```

The default value for `bool` is false, so I can be lazy and just return `default`

You can use pattern matching with `is` to check and extract the values in a single clean line :

```
if(MyFunc(true) is (true,var name1,var name2)){
 Console.WriteLine("AAA");
}

if(MyFunc(false) is (true,var name3,var name4)){
 Console.WriteLine("Should never enter here");
}
```

This will print only `"AAA"`

**Go style**

Go uses tuples for multi-value results the same way for now as it has no exceptions yet. This results in convoluted control flow and introduces the possibility of ignoring errors. Instead of a flag though, by convention the last tuple field is an error message :

```
func f1(arg int) (int, error) {
    if arg == 42 {
        return -1, errors.New("can't work with 42")
    }
    return arg + 3, nil
}

...

if r, e := f1(i); e != nil {
    fmt.Println("f1 failed:", e)
} else {
    fmt.Println("f1 worked:", r)
}
```

The same thing can be done in C# by adding an `error` field in the tuple and matching on null :

```
(int i,string? error) F1(int arg)
{
    return arg==42? (-1,"Can't work with 42")
                    :(arg+3,null);
}

...


var (i,error) =F1(42);
if (error is string err)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"F1 failed: {err}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"F1 worked: {i}");
}
```

Or

```
switch (F1(42)) 
{
    case (_,string error):
        Console.WriteLine($"F1 failed: {error}");
        break;
    case (int i,null):
        Console.WriteLine($"F1 worked: {i}");
        break;
}
```

Or, with switch expressions :

```
var output = F1(43) switch {
    (_,string error)=>$"F1 failed: {error}",
    (int i,null)    =>$"F1 worked: {i}"
};
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this .. my coding style usually first checks for error and return but I can't get this to work .. if I do your second example then after I can't access name3 and name 4 .. why ?

Comment: @kofifus what's the problem? I wrote and tested this code in LinqPad and copied it here as-is. It works. It *does* check for errors. That's what `is (true,...)` does, it checks for the success flag *and* extracts the values. If you want to do something on failure, add an `else`

Comment: Your code works but you can't access the variables after it !

Comment: @kofifus You should be able to, they are returned as a Tuple type. Maybe try work your way through this https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/06/intro-to-c-tuples/

Answer (score 1):

This approach could work if the tuple is not supposed to be used for anything if the return value is false. When that happens, we just provide a default tuple (which should be promptly ignored) rather than trying to communicate that it is null via a nullable type.

```
static bool Test(T1 param, out (Type1 name1, Type2 name2) result)
{
    try
    {
        //Successful case
        result = ( X, Y );
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        //Failure case
        result = (default(Type1), default(Type1));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now all the caller needs to write is:

```
if (Test(param, out var result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your results were {0} and {1}", result.name1, result.name2);
}
```

Comment: I agree, that is actually what I ended up doing ATM, I personally don't like the out parameter .. to me output should be on the left and input only should be on the right .. but maybe this is the best way